# Uneven spacing between every other button

Tags: html, css

I have a set of buttons (made with `<a></a>` or `button` the effect is the same) which are `inline-block` elements.

When I put many of them inline, spacing between them is not even.
Every other button have different spacing.

**Please note** that I am not trying to remove the space between buttons, I want it to be even.

The difference is about `1px` between first and second button, but second and third have as it appears to be `2px` spacing. The pattern then continues. I put black and arrow on matched spacings so you can see the pattern.

[image]

**CSS**

```css
.btn,
button,
input[type='button'],
input[type='reset'],
input[type='submit'] {
  @include transitions;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: ($baseline/2) 0;
  padding: .6em 2em;
  background: $default;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <a class="btn bg-green" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
        <a class="btn bg-yellow" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
        <a class="btn bg-red" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
        <a class="btn bg-blue" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
        <a class="btn bg-silver" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
        <a class="btn bg-gray" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
```

[image]

Here you can see better how spacing is uneven

Comment: Spacing seems fine - see example https://jsfiddle.net/tnfLc58h/2/

Comment: You really should create a demo that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: That's not plain vanilla CSS.

Comment: @aphextwix the OP appears to be using Sass but your example is not doing so

Comment: baseline is 20px so 20/2 = 10px on margin so its not something that would couse the problem

Comment: @scniro Ah yes. A keen eye you have there sir.

Comment: @riogrande Well call me naive but your margin property might be related to a margin issue ;)

Comment: @riogrande But Pangloss is right, you need to recreate the issue.

Comment: @scniro tried but same result

Comment: Make sure `font-size` and spacing between links is consistent.
Also, either share the link or recreate it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/570a65r7/ here is the fiddle but the spacings are god there....

Comment: ok give me a minute to upload it, in meantime please look at another image i put in question

Comment: Please guys look at the new image i edited, call me crazy but the spacing is bigger

Comment: http://marioloncarek.com/stack/doc/ui.html Here is the live link please scroll until buttons

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgdq2946/) is the minimal demo to reproduce the issue, very interesting! The last gap looks smaller than the rest, tested both Firefox and Chrome on the Mac.

Comment: I cant reproduce the bug anywhere... only live demo and images :(

Comment: I can see the issue here, I can't say why but it must be something to do with the whitespace, and it can be fixed see the [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hgdq2946/1/). Hope that helps.

Comment: your suggestion need font-size:0 on body to work? im not feeling like doing that ..

Comment: Come on, that is just an example as a container.

Comment: Yea but that should like modular button used everywhere, no container needed

Comment: @Pangloss look at dippas answer below, what the hell is going on with my font

Comment: Nothing wrong with your font, it's the font-size matters I guess, also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) but I don't know why the whitespace renders differently.

Comment: I know about that, and this post is about removing it, im not trying that, im fine with the space between, just need it to be the same

Comment: I can't explain, that's way I didn't post an answer, I do see the issue even with the default sans-serif font.

Comment: Thanks for everything friend!

Comment: You're welcome, it is very interesting, I might start a bounty some time, will leave you a comment if I found out an answer that can explain everything.

Comment: Yea that would be great i will start a bounty when ever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could figure it out , the problem to me seems to be the `sofia` `font` set on `body`, so:

- if you change for `Arial`, you'll see that there is no difference in the gaps.

  or
- you can increase your current `font-size` from `15px` to `16px` and keep the  `sofia`

Comment: Ok, what the hell? Also works when font-size is 14px. Why would font do that? Your answer is correct tho

Answer (score 1):

dippas answer correctly points out that the font is the problem. To be more specific, it is the font used for the space inbetween the buttons that is the problem. If you dont want to change the font on your buttons, here are some workarounds:

1. Change the body font, but have `sofia` for the buttons
2. Remove the spaces between the buttons and use margin instead. There are two ways to do this:
   1) Put exactly no whitespace between adjacent buttons or, 
   2) Use HTML comments to comment out all whitespace

```html
<!-- No whitespace inbetween -->
<a class="btn"></a><a class="btn"></a>

<a class="btn"></a><!-- Or, comment it out
--><a class="btn></a>
```

3. Change to block elements, set width: auto, float them all left, then add a specific margin to them.

Comment: Great advice's! Thanks a lot